# If you ever get strange syntax errors in your R.java file, then check for this issue

Tags: android

Maybe this will help someone avoid some pain.

While doing some GUI work, I got the typical id cannot be resolved error 
(R.id hell I call it).
"No problem, I'll just check my xml files", but I couldn't find any issue (no clue in console).

But I did notice further down the error list several goofy syntax errors in R.java such as...

*Illegal modifier for the class array; only public, abstract & final are permitted*

So I figured something must be broke in the code that generates it.
The beginning of my R.java file looked like this...

```
public final class R {
    public static final class  {
        public static final int VertBar=0x7f0a0000;
    }
    public static final class array {
        public static final int AnswerActionValues=0x7f060001;
        public static final int AnswerActionsNames=0x7f060000;
    }
```

Notice the missing class name in the first class?
Well the clue was the VertBar constant.

This led me to my layout which had...

```
<View
android:id="@+/VertBar"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF"></View>
```

Notice anything strange??

I somehow deleted the id portion of "@+id/VertBar" and just had "@+/VertBar" 
This causes the auto generator to create a class with no name! I guess @+ with no id means just add a constant in an unnamed class.

In short every R.id hell issue I've had so far has been do to the keyboard-chair interface (me).

Comment: Please consider posting the resolution to your question as an answer to your question. This would make it more clear that it has been answered.